# Solving $E[h \dot{f}]=-2 E[h^2 f] + E[h f]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Suppose $f(i,t): R^+\times R^+ \rightarrow R^+$, $f(0, t)=1$ and $h(i)$ is a given function like $h(i)=(1+i)^{-2}$

How would I find $f$ satisfying the following differential equation?

$$\int \mathrm{d}i\ \frac{d}{dt} f(i, t) h(i)  = -2\int \mathrm{d} i\ h(i)^2 f(i, t) + \int \mathrm{d} i\ h(i) f(i, t)$$

Comment: Since the Expected Value is a linear operator, I think you will have that
$ E[h \dot{f}]=-2 E[h^2 f] + E[h f]$ is equivalent to: $$E[h \dot{f}+2 h^2 f-h f]=0$$ so you need to solve $$h \dot{f}+2 h^2 f-h f=0$$, right?

Comment: OK, good point, that view makes it pretty straightforward

Comment: At least [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5Bf%5Bx%2Ct%5D%2Ct%5D*h%5Bx%5D%2Bf%5Bx%2Ct%5D*%282*%28h%5Bx%5D%29%5E2-h%5Bx%5D%29%3D0) can solve the last equation.